# How can i get the issuer or footer or any additional data in GO paseto v2(public)

Tags: go, go-fiber, paseto

```
func GetToken(user int) (string, error) {
    v2 := paseto.NewV2()
    b, _ := hex.DecodeString(PrivateKey)
    privateKey := ed25519.PrivateKey(b)
    jsonToken := paseto.JSONToken{
        Expiration: time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour),
        Issuer:     strconv.Itoa(user),
        IssuedAt:   time.Now(),
    }
    footer := strconv.Itoa(user)

    token, err := v2.Sign(privateKey, jsonToken, footer)
    return token, err
}
```

I have a code for generate token with addition data like issuer or footer. But I cannot find any way to get that information after token verified token.

```
func VerifyToken(token string) bool {
    v2 := paseto.NewV2()
    b, _ := hex.DecodeString(PublicKey)
    publicKEY := ed25519.PublicKey(b)
    var newJsonToken paseto.JSONToken
    var newFooter string
    err := v2.Verify(token, publicKEY, &newJsonToken, &newFooter)
    return err == nil
}
```

Can anyone help me out to get issuer or footer or any additional data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I am using public mode and my token be like "v2.public.$$$$$...".
after I have verified my token, I got all data like issuer from "newJsonToken"

```
func VerifyToken(token string) bool {
    v2 := paseto.NewV2()
    b, _ := hex.DecodeString(PublicKey)
    publicKEY := ed25519.PublicKey(b)
    var newJsonToken paseto.JSONToken
    var newFooter string
    err := v2.Verify(token, publicKEY, &newJsonToken, &newFooter)
    fmt.Println("Json token: ",newJsonToken.Issuer)
    return err == nil
}
```

here i got the issuer which I append to "GetToken" function.
Thank you.